# only allow snap starting or ending points of lineString in Openlayers3

Tags: openlayers-3

I am working a Web application with Openlayers3, there is a question about snapping. I only want to snap the starting point or ending point (not snap between 2 points) of lineString, and only allow to modify on nodes (disable creating node between 2 nodes). Glad to see any help about it.

Answer (score 1):

create a point vector layer and populate it with start end points of the lines you want to be used for snapping.
Then initialise your snapping control and pass the source of this vector layer to snap interaction.